# jQuery toggle css property value (not class)?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

What’s the shortest way to toggle a css property value between two values?

I’m attempting to solve the CSS transition 0/auto problem.

Here’s my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var height = $('#menu').prop('scrollHeight');

    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#menu").css('height', height);
    });

})
```

Here’s my CSS:

```
#toggle {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    transition: height 1s ease 0.2s;
}
```

It works for opening the menu. But it doesn’t close the menu, of course.

Is there a function to toggle a CSS property? A single function that toggles the height property between 0 and the value retrieved with `.prop('scrollHeight')`?

I want to keep it as short as possible. I hope there’s a way so I don’t need to use `if` statements to check for the value of the height property.

Note: `.toggleClass` is not useful in this scenario.

Comment: Why isn't `toggleClass` useful? Assign the different CSS properties to two classes, and toggle between them.

Comment: If you want to animate the transition, you can use `.animate({height: "toggle" })`. It will toggle between 0 and the height in the CSS.

Comment: @Barmar but the height in the CSS IS 0

Comment: Do it the other way around. Put the expanded height in the CSS, and use jQuery to set it to `0` when the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    if($('#menu').height() != height){
        $("#menu").css('height', height);
    }
    else{
        $("#menu").css('height', '0px');
    }
});
```

Comment: It should be `$("#menu").height()`. Everything in jQuery is a function, not a property accessor.